# How to show more of truncated post text without leave the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to limit the content of post's blog to a certain number of characters then add a link "show more" to show the rest of post, i found this solution :

```
<%= truncate post.content, length: 160 %>
<%= link_to 'read more', post %>
```

but here the read more will show the post in separate page, what i want is to show the rest of post without leaving or refreshing the page like we see in facebook for example

Answer (score 1):

You are probably wanting to do that with jQuery. 
This [plugin](http://jedfoster.com/Readmore.js/) is great.